# Is it allowed to combine $ref with other keywords in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm learning JSON Schema for one of the open-source projects. Have a question concerning combining an already defined schema with some additional keywords.

Assume I've defined some schema which is available via the reference, for example `#/definitions/positiveInteger`.

Now I would like to refer to that type and extend it with few other keywords. For instance, I'd like to add `enum` or `description`.

Is it allowed to do this:

```
{
    "$ref" : "#/definitions/positiveInteger",
    "description" : "This is positive integer with enums",
    "enum" : [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
}
```

Or do I have to do this:

```
{
    "allOf" : [ { "$ref" : "#/definitions/positiveInteger" } ],
    "description" : "This is positive integer with enums",
    "enum" : [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
}
```

I could not find the formal reference for that and not sure how validation tools would react.

Basically I have two question here:

- Should the validation keyword like `enum` work in the first case?
- Will be there any conflicts if I include a metadata keyword like `description` next to `$ref` like in the first case?

I'd actually prefer to inline `$ref`s and not to include them in `allOf` and kinds but not sure if this is legal. I couldn't even find a description of `$ref` in the spec (just a couple of examples).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `allOf` to extend a definition.  Here is the relevant documentation.

> Any members other than "$ref" in a JSON Reference object SHALL be ignored.
>
> - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03#section-3

Answer (score 1):

From Draft 2019-09, $ref and other properties can co-exist together.

[JSON Schema Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-00#section-8.2.3.1)

Although the spec seems a little unclear on what happens when the reference schema and the importing schema declare the same properties

Comment: You can refer to json-schema test suite for refs: https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite/blob/main/tests/draft2019-09/ref.json It contains many examples with $ref. In the draft 2019 the $ref must refer to schema (or to another $ref). This refrenced schema  works like one more validator keyword. So if we have the same property near the $ref and inside refrenced schema, then both of them should be applied. I suppose it works like to allOff between the refrenced schema and the sibling (to $ref) properties

Comment: Look for tests with names "ref applies alongside sibling keywords" and "ref creates new scope when adjacent to keywords" to understand the expected behavior